# The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, identity, eclipselink

There have been [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762573/should-embeddable-jpa-class-implement-equals-and-hashcode) [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147166/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-baseentity-of-jpa) here about JPA entities and which `hashCode()`/`equals()` implementation should be used for JPA entity classes.  Most (if not all) of them depend on Hibernate, but I'd like to discuss them JPA-implementation-neutrally (I am using EclipseLink, by the way).

All possible implementations are having their own **advantages** and **disadvantages** regarding:

- **`hashCode()`/`equals()`** contract **conformity** (immutability) for `List`/`Set` operations
- Whether **identical** objects (e.g. from different sessions, dynamic proxies from lazily-loaded data structures) can be detected
- Whether entities behave correctly in **detached (or non-persisted) state**

As far I can see, there are **three options**:

1. Do not override them; rely on `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()`

   - `hashCode()`/`equals()` work
   - cannot identify identical objects, problems with dynamic proxies
   - no problems with detached entities
2. Override them, based on the **primary key**

   - `hashCode()`/`equals()` are broken
   - correct identity (for all managed entities)
   - problems with detached entities
3. Override them, based on the **Business-Id** (non-primary key fields; what about foreign keys?)

   - `hashCode()`/`equals()` are broken
   - correct identity (for all managed entities)
   - no problems with detached entities

**My questions are:**

1. Did I miss an option and/or pro/con point?
2. What option did you choose and why?

**UPDATE 1:**

By "`hashCode()`/`equals()` are broken", I mean that successive `hashCode()` invocations may return differing values, which is (when correctly implemented) not broken in the sense of the `Object` API documentation, but which causes problems when trying to retrieve a changed entity from a `Map`,  `Set` or other hash-based `Collection`.  Consequently, JPA implementations (at least EclipseLink) will not work correctly in some cases.

**UPDATE 2:**

Thank you for your answers -- most of them have remarkable quality.
Unfortunately, I am still unsure which approach will be the best for a real-life application, or how to determine the best approach for my application.  So, I'll keep the question open and hope for some more discussions and/or opinions.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "hashCode()/equals() broken"

Comment: @nanda: from Object.hashCode() javadoc: "Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer" and "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result." which is violated in option 2 and 3.

Comment: They wouldn't be "broken" in that sense then, as in option 2 and 3 you would be implementing both equals() and hashCode() using the same strategy.

Comment: @matt b option 2's hashCode() will change after persist(), option 3's hashCode() will change if some business field changes which I would call "broken" in the sense of the equals() method javadoc comment and Joshua Blochs book "Effective Java".

Comment: That is not true of option 3. hashCode() and equals() should be using the same criteria, therefore if one of your fields change, yes the hashcode() method will return a different value for the same instance than it previous did, but so will equals(). You've left off the second part of the sentence from the hashcode() javadoc: _Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, **provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified**._

Comment: @matt b Maybe I am missunderstanding the contract (I am not a native english speaker) but I am interpreting "provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified" as **"there's an exception of the rule if fields have been changed on which the equals method does not rely on"** which is not true in option 3 because both rely on the same fields (which all may change).

Comment: Actually that part of the sentence means the opposite - calling `hashcode()` on the same object instance should return the same value, unless any fields used in the `equals()` implementation change. In other words, if you have three fields in your class and your `equals()` method uses only two of them to determine equality of instances, then you can expect the `hashcode()` return value to change if you change one of those field's values - which makes sense when you consider that this object instance is no longer "equal" to the value that the old instance represented.

Comment: Thank you, matt-b - I've updated my question to reflect your correct statements.

Comment: "problems when trying to retrieve a changed entity from a Map, Set or other hash-based Collections"... this should be "problems when trying to retrieve a changed entity from a HashMap, HashSet or other hash-based Collections"

Comment: What are your thoughts on including your optimistic locking property, if you use one, in your hashCode()? Perhaps this deserves its own question.

Comment: What do you mean problems with detached entities?

Comment: @AndreiI If you add a not-yet-persisted entity into a hash-based collection and if the entity's hashCode relies on the PK, its hashcode will change after persisting it (because its PK will most probably be set), hence violating the hash-based collection's contract which leads to unpredictable results

Comment: @MRalwasser not-yet-persisted is not the same as detached. According to the JPA spec, "a detached entity instance is an instance with a **persistent** identity that is not (or no longer)
associated with a persistence context". Please correct the question. Also, when when you say problems with yet-not-persisted entities, you mean actually the cause for the `hashCode/equals() broken` problem. So you might consider to reformulate the three points.

Comment: What do you mean by `problems with dynamic proxies`?

Comment: If I understand the answers correctly then there is a 4th not-listed option which has the advantages of all the 3 listed options. That is when you create an entity (calling new) you also assign a large random number to its JPA ID (with the default GenerationType assigned). Now you can use an equals/hashcode based on this random number. The probability that two such random numbers collide is small.

Comment: @jsegedus - That is not correct. You are probably referring to UUID generation - this should give you a clearer picture. http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1

Comment: Best article I've read on SO in so many years.

Comment: @jhegedus From the book [Spring Boot Persistence Best Practices](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484256251) by Anghel Leonard, he hardcoded `2021` as the return value of the `hashCode` method of child class (the _many_ side).

Comment: According to your definition of `hashCode / equals are broken` which takes hash-based collection or map into consideration (which the element/key is mutable, possible in a Hibernate context), Option 3 (Business-Id) should **not** break hashCode and equals. For example, `BookEntity`'s `isbn` field can be used for `equals` and `hashCode` as this information is available when new object is created and will remain unchanged and be consistent across all entity state transitions.

Comment: There is one more option: compare by all fields (the naive implementation)

Comment: Accordin last (Hopefully the final) jpa-buddy investigation, little adapted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78077907/548473

Answer (score 158):

Read this very nice article on the subject: [Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity](https://web.archive.org/web/20171211235806/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html).

The conclusion of the article goes like this:

> Object identity is deceptively hard to implement correctly when
>   objects are persisted to a database. However, the problems stem
>   entirely from allowing objects to exist without an id before they are
>   saved. We can solve these problems by taking the responsibility of
>   assigning object IDs away from object-relational mapping frameworks
>   such as Hibernate. Instead, object IDs can be assigned as soon as the
>   object is instantiated. This makes object identity simple and
>   error-free, and reduces the amount of code needed in the domain model.

Comment: No, that is not a nice article. That is a **freaking great** article on the subject, and it should be required reading for every JPA programmer! +1!

Comment: Yup I am using the same solution. Not letting the DB generate the ID has other advantages too, such as being able to create an object and already create other objects that reference it before persisting it. This can remove latency and multiple request/response cycles in client-server apps. If you need inspiration for such a solution, check out my projects: [suid.js](http://download.github.io/suid/) and [suid-server-java](http://download.github.io/suid-server-java/). Basically `suid.js` fetches ID blocks from `suid-server-java` which you can then get and use client-side.

Comment: This is simply insane. I'm new to hibernate workings under the hood, was writing unit tests, and found out that I can't delete an object from a set after modifying it, concluded that it is because of the hashcode change, but was unable to understand how to solve. The article is simple gorgeous!

Comment: It is a great article. However, for people who see the link for the first time, I would suggest that it might be an overkill for most applications. The other 3 options listed on this page should more or less solve the issue in multiple ways.

Comment: Does Hibernate/JPA use the equals and hashcode method of an entity to check if the record already exists in the database?

Comment: @TusharBanne I don't exactly know what it uses it for but I have seen exception in Hibernate related to the `hashCode` method so it's safe to say that it does use it

Answer (score 70):

I always override equals/hashcode and implement it based on the business id. Seems the most reasonable solution for me. See the following [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode).

> To sum all this stuff up, here is a listing of what will work or won't work with the different ways to handle equals/hashCode: [image]

**EDIT**:

To explain why this works for me:

1. I don't usually use hashed-based collection (HashMap/HashSet) in my JPA application. If I must, I prefer to create UniqueList solution.
2. I think changing business id on runtime is not a best practice for any database application. On rare cases where there is no other solution, I'd do special treatment like remove the element and put it back to the hashed-based collection.
3. For my model, I set the business id on constructor and doesn't provide setters for it. I let JPA implementation to change the **field** instead of the property.
4. UUID solution seems to be overkill. Why UUID if you have natural business id? I would after all set the uniqueness of the business id in the database. Why having **THREE** indexes for each table in the database then?

Comment: But this table is lacking a fifth line "works with List/Sets" (if you think of removing an entity which is part of a Set from a OneToMany mapping) which would be answered "No" on the last two options because its hashCode() changes which violates its contract.

Comment: See the comment on the question. You seems to misunderstand the equals/hashcode contract

Comment: @MRalwasser: I think you mean the right thing, it's just not the equals/hashCode() contract itself which is violated. But a mutable equals/hashCode does create problems with the *Set* contract.

Comment: @MRalwasser: The hashcode can only change if the business ID changes, and the point is that the business ID *does not* change. So the hashcode doesn't change, and this works perfectly with hashed collections.

Comment: What if you are creating a new entity for which the id is assigned by the database, e.g., from a sequence? In that case the id does change (null first, a value after persistence). How do you handle that?

Comment: What if you don't have a natural business key? For example in case of a two dimensional point, Point(X,Y), in a graph-drawing application? How would you store that point as an Entity?

Comment: Why not use (2) with equals() and hashCode() that fallback to the object's identity if ID is not set yet? At least it allow multiple new instances in Set. But of course such hashCode() still change after persist new entity. But for entities without natural business key (in real world much of them are still without except User-like entities used in ALL answers here) it is decent solution.

Answer (score 44):

I personally already used all of these three strategies in different projects. And I must say that option 1 is in my opinion the most practicable in a real life app. In my experience breaking `hashCode()`/`equals()` conformity leads to many crazy bugs as you will every time end up in situations where the result of equality changes after an entity has been added to a collection.

But there are further options (also with their pros and cons):

---

a) `hashCode`/`equals` based on a set of **immutable**, **not null**, **constructor assigned**, fields

(+) all three criteria are guaranteed

(-) field values must be available to create a new instance

(-) complicates handling if you must change one of then

---

b) `hashCode`/`equals` based on a primary key that is assigned by the application (in the constructor) instead of JPA

(+) all three criteria are guaranteed

(-) you cannot take advantage of simple reliable ID generation strategies like DB sequences

(-) complicated if new entities are created in a distributed environment (client/server) or app server cluster

---

c) `hashCode`/`equals` based on a [UUID](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) assigned by the constructor of the entity

(+) all three criteria are guaranteed

(-) overhead of UUID generation

(-) may be a little risk that twice the same UUID is used, depending on algorithm used (may be detected by an unique index on DB)

Comment: I'm fan of **Option 1** and **Approach C** also. Do nothing till you absolutely need it is the more agile approach.

Comment: +1 for option (b). IMHO, if an entity has a natural business ID, then that should also be its database primary key. That's simple, straightforward, good database design. If it doesn't have such an ID, then a surrogate key is needed. If you set that at object creation, then everything else is simple. It's when people don't use a natural key, *and* don't generate a surrogate key early that they get into trouble. As for complexity in implementation - yes, there is some. But really not a lot, and it can be done a very generic way that solves it once for all entities.

Comment: I also prefer option 1, but then how to write unit test to assert the full equality is a big problem, because we have to implement the equals method for `Collection`.

Comment: Overhead of UUID generation is a minus?  How does that compare to actually storing the data in a database?

Answer (score 37):

If you want to use `equals()/hashCode()` for your Sets, in the sense that the *same entity* can only be in there once, then there is only one option: Option 2. That's because a **primary key** for an entity by definition never changes (if somebody indeed updates it, it's not the same entity anymore)

You should take that literally: Since your `equals()/hashCode()` are based on the primary key, you must not use these methods, until the primary key is set. So you shouldn't put entities in the set, until they're assigned a primary key. (Yes, UUIDs and similar concepts may help to assign primary keys early.)

Now, it's theoretically also possible to achieve that with Option 3, even though so-called "business-keys" have the nasty drawback that they can change: "All you'll have to do is delete the already inserted entities from the set(s), and re-insert them." That is true - but it also means, that in a distributed system, you'll have to make sure, that this is done absolutely everywhere the data has been inserted to (and you'll have to make sure, that the update is performed, before other things occur). You'll need a sophisticated update mechanism, especially if some remote systems aren't currently reachable...

Option 1 can only be used, if all the objects in your sets are from the same Hibernate session. The Hibernate documentation makes this very clear in chapter [13.1.3. Considering object identity](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-identity):

> Within a Session the application can safely use == to compare objects.
>
> However, an application that uses == outside of a Session might produce unexpected results. This might occur even in some unexpected places. For example, if you put two detached instances into the same Set, both might have the same database identity (i.e., they represent the same row). JVM identity, however, is by definition not guaranteed for instances in a detached state. The developer has to override the equals() and hashCode() methods in persistent classes and implement their own notion of object equality.

It continues to argue in favor of Option 3:

> There is one caveat: never use the database identifier to implement equality. Use a business key that is a combination of unique, usually immutable, attributes. The database identifier will change if a transient object is made persistent. If the transient instance (usually together with detached instances) is held in a Set, changing the hashcode breaks the contract of the Set.

This is true, **if** you

- cannot assign the id early (e.g. by using UUIDs)
- and yet you absolutely want to put your objects in sets while they're in transient state.

Otherwise, you're free to choose Option 2.

Then it mentions the need for a relative stability:

> Attributes for business keys do not have to be as stable as database primary keys; you only have to guarantee stability as long as the objects are in the same Set.

This is correct. The practical problem I see with this is: If you can't guarantee absolute stability, how will you be able to guarantee stability "as long as the objects are in the same Set". I can imagine some special cases (like using sets only for a conversation and then throwing it away), but I would question the general practicability of this.

---

Short version:

- Option 1 can only be used with objects within a single session.
- If you can, use Option 2. (Assign PK as early as possible, because you can't use the objects in sets until the PK is assigned.)
- If you can guarantee relative stability, you can use Option 3. But be careful with this.

Comment: Your assumption that the primary key never changes is false.  Eg, Hibernate only allocates the primary key when the session is saved.  So, if you use the primary key as your hashCode the result of hashCode() before you first save the object and after you first save the object will be different.  Worse, before you save the session, two newly created objects will have the same hashCode and can overwrite each other when added to collections.  You may find yourself having to force a save/flush immediately on object creation to use that approach.

Comment: @William: The primary key of an **entity** doesn't change. The id property of the mapped **object** may change. This occurs, as you explained, especially when a *transient* object is made *persistent*. Please read the part of my answer carefully, where I said about the equals/hashCode methods: "you must not use these methods, until the primary key is set."

Comment: Totally agree. With option 2, you're also able to factor out equals/hashcode in a super class and have it re-used by all you entities.

Answer (score 36):

We usually have two IDs in our entities:

1. Is for persistence layer only (so that persistence provider and database can figure out relationships between objects).
2. Is for our application needs (`equals()` and `hashCode()` in particular)

Take a look:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;  // Persistence ID
    private UUID uuid; // Business ID

    // assuming all fields are subject to change
    // If we forbid users change their email or screenName we can use these
    // fields for business ID instead, but generally that's not the case
    private String screenName;
    private String email;

    // I don't put UUID generation in constructor for performance reasons. 
    // I call setUuid() when I create a new entity
    public User() {
    }

    // This method is only called when a brand new entity is added to 
    // persistence context - I add it as a safety net only but it might work 
    // for you. In some cases (say, when I add this entity to some set before 
    // calling em.persist()) setting a UUID might be too late. If I get a log 
    // output it means that I forgot to call setUuid() somewhere.
    @PrePersist
    public void ensureUuid() {
        if (getUuid() == null) {
            log.warn(format("User's UUID wasn't set on time. " 
                + "uuid: %s, name: %s, email: %s",
                getUuid(), getScreenName(), getEmail()));
            setUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
        }
    }

    // equals() and hashCode() rely on non-changing data only. Thus we 
    // guarantee that no matter how field values are changed we won't 
    // lose our entity in hash-based Sets.
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getUuid().hashCode();
    }

    // Note that I don't use direct field access inside my entity classes and
    // call getters instead. That's because Persistence provider (PP) might
    // want to load entity data lazily. And I don't use 
    //    this.getClass() == other.getClass() 
    // for the same reason. In order to support laziness PP might need to wrap
    // my entity object in some kind of proxy, i.e. subclassing it.
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof User))
            return false;
        return getUuid().equals(((User) obj).getUuid());
    }

    // Getters and setters follow
}
```

---

**EDIT:** to clarify my point regarding calls to `setUuid()` method. Here's a typical scenario:

```
User user = new User();
// user.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID()); // I should have called it here
user.setName("Master Yoda");
user.setEmail("yoda@jedicouncil.org");

jediSet.add(user); // here's bug - we forgot to set UUID and 
                   //we won't find Yoda in Jedi set

em.persist(user); // ensureUuid() was called and printed the log for me.

jediCouncilSet.add(user); // Ok, we got a UUID now
```

When I run my tests and see the log output I fix the problem:

```
User user = new User();
user.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
```

Alternatively, one can provide a separate constructor:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;  // Persistence ID
    private UUID uuid; // Business ID

    ... // fields

    // Constructor for Persistence provider to use
    public User() {
    }

    // Constructor I use when creating new entities
    public User(UUID uuid) {
        setUuid(uuid);
    }

    ... // rest of the entity.
}
```

So my example would look like this:

```
User user = new User(UUID.randomUUID());
...
jediSet.add(user); // no bug this time

em.persist(user); // and no log output
```

I use a default constructor and a setter, but you may find two-constructors approach more suitable for you.

Comment: I really like the `ensureUuid()` idea - it's simple, but probably very effective, if you have a habit of checking the logs regularly (in fact, I think I'm going to use this).  The part I don't get (yet) is this: If the uuid can change, then what does it buy you (you'd still have the HashSet problem)? If it can't change, then why don't you use it as the primary key?

Comment: Well, UUID *can* change from a pure language perspective. But in fact in my code I call setUuid() only on new entities before they are added to persistence context. I keep setter around for persistence provider to use.

Regarding two IDs: the first ID is for persistence provider and database. Our primary ind foreign keys are integers and all those UUIDs are just data from db perspective. But when PP loads entities and puts them into collections these UUIDs start to play.

It might be somewhat confusing first, but it works great.

Comment: I believe, that this is a correct and good solution. It may also have a little performance advantage, because integers usually perform better in database indexes than uuids. But apart from that, you could probably eliminate the current integer id property, and replace it with the (application assigned) uuid?

Comment: Sure, why not? Just use UUID as a db primary key - and actually quite a lot of people (especially new developers coming to my team :-) suggest just that. That would remove quite a bit of ambiguity - one ID instead of two. The drawback like you said is performance. So it's a tradeoff: more performance at cost of bigger complexity. Here the complexity is quite manageable once you get used to it.

Comment: How is this different to using the default `hashCode`/`equals` methods for JVM equality and `id` for persistence equality? This doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: It works in cases when you have several entity objects pointing to the same row in a database. `Object`'s `equals()` would return `false` in this case. UUID-based `equals()` returns `true`.

Comment: I like this approach but I don't really get why you have an explicit method for setting the UUID on a new entity? Why not simply do this: `private UUID uuid= UUID.randomUUID();`. This prevents the need of explicitly setting or unintentionally changing an existing UUID. One condition of course is that the UUID generation must be lightweight. Of course I only use a UUID if there is no other business key available, in the above case I would probably use the email address as a business key (if mandatory) and no UUID (and only have 1 constructor available, one that takes the email address as arg).

Comment: Yep, both your suggestions are correct. Actually, I use the approach listed above only in cases when I can't use UUIDs as database keys - which is when performance of JOINs is critical. Otherwise I just go with UUIDs as business and DB keys. That simplifies code quite a lot.

Comment: @Andrew - This is called a "surrogate key" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key, you should mention that term in your answer.

Comment: -1 - i don't see any reason to have two IDs, and so two kinds of identity. This seems completely pointless and potentially harmful to me.

Comment: @TomAnderson well, I personally don't like an idea of having two ids either. But when you create a new entity object you need an id so you can put it into collections before saving. Thus, you need to generate ID on Java side (so-called "business key") - usually it's either business fields (say, email) or a UUID. But then database would want it's own id. We could go with business key here as well but then DBA would complain about poor performance of non-integer keys. Thus two keys unless you can get away with only one.

Comment: A UUID like that would be an absolutely fine database key. If your DBA complains about using one, he's incompetent. Seriously. The database *does not* need its own ID. Relational databases have been built from the very beginning to support the use of business-meaningful columns as keys.

Comment: @TomAnderson Well, that argument is partially true. SQL was _designed_ to enable fast query execution but people still optimize queries quite often. Similary, not-integer keys are fast but they are still _quite slower_ than integer keys (ints fit into CPU registers, they take less cache space, etc.). Besides, often databases are used by several applications and we aren't allowed to change the underlying table structure while adding another column for UUIDs is always fine. As always the right answer is 'it depends'.

Comment: @TomAnderson Instead of arguing I'd like to hear about your take on that problem. Suppose you have an entity that can be part of some persistent collection. How would you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` that would work fine for normal entities, detached entities and proxy objects? What if we stuck with integer DB keys? I'd love to see a solution simpler than mine!

Comment: I don't believe that non-integer keys are significantly slower than integer keys; i think they're both small enough that their size does not dominate access costs. However, of course, if performance is important, and profiling shows that an integer key would be preferable to a non-integer one, then an integer key has to be used.

Comment: Sorry for criticising your solution without pointing to one i would prefer. In short, i would give objects a single ID field, i would implement equals and hashCode based on it, and i would generate its value on object creation, rather than when saving to the database. That way, all forms of the object work the same way: non-persistent, persistent, and detached. Hibernate proxies (or similar) should also work correctly, and i think would not even need to be hydrated to handle equals and hashCode calls.

Comment: If you can use a UUID for a key, then that's a reasonable thing to do, and makes generation easy. If you can't, or would rather not, then i would suggest generating IDs from a persistent counter (possibly obfuscated). This is fairly simple, but probably merits an answer to explain it; i will try to write one in the next few days.

Answer (score 29):

1. If you have a business key, then you should use that for `equals` and [`hashCode`](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/).
2. If you don't have a business key, you should not leave it with the default `Object` equals and hashCode implementations because that does not work after you `merge` and entity.
3. You can use the entity identifier in the [`equals`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-entity-identifier/) method only if the `hashCode` implementation returns a constant value, like this:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Book {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private Long id;

       private String title;

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (this == o) return true;
           if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
           Book book = (Book) o;
           return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), book.getId());
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return getClass().hashCode();
       }

       //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
   }
   ```

Check out this [test case on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/equality/IdEqualityTest.java) that proves this solution works like a charm.

Comment: Which is better: (1) http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html or (2) https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/? Solution  (2) is easier than (1). So why should I use (1). Are the effects of both the same? Do both guarantee the same solution?

Comment: And with your solution: "the hashCode value does not change" between the same instances. This has the same behaviour as if it were the "same" uuid (from solution (1)) being compared. Am I right?

Comment: If (2) works under every state, why should I bother with "business key" at all?

Comment: And store the UUID in the database and increase the footprint of the record and in the buffer pool? I think this can lead to more performance issues on the long run than the unique hashCode. As for the other solution, you can check it out to see if it provides consistency across all entity state transitions. You can find the [test that checks that on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/ba1fa563ae5832e74cd9279c5bad00614f76f4fd/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/equality/AbstractEqualityCheckTest.java).

Comment: I adapted your solution and it works very well. The solution of (1) is not better than yours. The only thing, which I wanted to know: why should I bother with searching for a "business key" to provide equals/hashCode - I can use your solution of (2) for all kind of entities, or? Are there any limitations in compare to using "business key"?

Comment: If you have an immutable business key, the hashCode can use it and it's going to benefit from multiple buckets, so it's worth using if you have one. Otherwise, just use the entity identifier as explained in my article.

Comment: You could also write getClass().hashCode() instead of the random 31.

Comment: You know, I think this is the first time I see a sound solution to this problem. Kudos!

Comment: When in doubt, just go to Vlad Mihalcea Dot Com 

Comment: @VladMihalcea Thanks a lot for this good explanations. I think this is the most proper way :) Could you please clarify me about these issues? >>>

Comment: **1.** Is it enought to use the unique field e.g. ISBN number in the equals and hashcode methods? Or do we also have to use `@NaturalId` annottaion and make necessary implementation?

Comment: **2.** As far as I see, if we have a unique field in our entity, we can just use this field in the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations of this entity. If there is not any unique field and there are not multiple fields that helps us to identify if the entity is unique, then we should use the approach you mentioned in your example code. Is it completely right?

Comment: @fredrick 1. If you have a NOT NULL UNIQUE key column, then you can use that one for `equals` and `hashCode`. You don't need to use `@NaturalId`. That's just for being able to fetch the entity by that business key column. 2. That's correct.

Comment: Actually I used `@NaturalId` in one of my project, but I did not exactly what is was. Now, do you mean that `@NaturalId` has no benefit for equals and hasCode implementations and only used for fetching the entity by that business key column?

Comment: @VladMihalcea What do you think about my last comment?

Comment: My previous comment already answered your subsequent question about NaturalId.

Comment: In this implementation, I think any instance of this entity would not be equal until they get an id value. Is that true?

Comment: And is this only for entity classes? or any class that has a mutable id field e.g. request dto? Do we also need to implement `implements Identifiable<Long>`  for our entity?

Comment: @devx Two distinct Objects that have a `null` identifier will end up having distinct ids after `persist`, so their identities are not equal. As for DTOs, it depends on whether you want to store them in mutable collections.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Thanks for reply. **#1** For this implementation, should we implement `Identifiable<Long>` for our entity as in the example (I am not sure it is related to the implementation)? **#2** And when we use `UUID`, I think we can also use it as `Identifiable<UUID>`, right?

Comment: The `Identifiable<Long>` is just an implementation detail that's not required by any choice of `equals` and `hashCode`. In fact, I'll remove it from the code example.

Comment: Yeah, now is better, thanks and voted up ;)

Comment: I have issues with solution 3, as it introduces surprising side effects like making it impossible to use the class in a HashSet and HashMap, a transient object of book X is different than the persisted object of the same book, no transient books can be equal. I see that it might work for JPA, but for Java in general it just looks dangerous. Would rather just omit it, as that would work fine with JPA without giving any such surprises in other contexts.

Comment: @Tobb A transient entity reference will be saved as a new record in the database table, so how can it be equal to an existing table record when the two entities will point to different table records? When it comes to JPA entities, equality is based on the table record identity. Anyway, the PK will be unique, so even from a Value perspective, two distinct entities cannot be equal. JPA entities are not generic in-memory objects that are cost-free. They have high inertia, as the cost to fetch 100k entities is many orders of magnitude greater than the overhead of using a single bucket.

Comment: If you run [this test case](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hpjp/hibernate/equality/IdEqualityTest.java#L38), you'll see that creating or fetching a large volume of Objects is significantly larger than the time it takes to call `contains` on a `Set` with a single bucket. You just assume that there are going to be problems while my tests on GitHub have already proven that this solution works like a charm.

Comment: It is not a record in a database table, it is a Java object. And thus, imho, it should behave like one. My main concern here isn't the movement of bits and bytes, but rather that it will be used by humans, and humans come with a lot of assumptions on how things work. If doing something unorthodox for the sake of bits and bytes, it should be made very clear to the humans why things are as they are and what the consequences are.

Comment: A JPA entity represents a table record. When the entity is in the state of Transient, it means it will become a table record. If you fetch it from the DB, the entity is associated with a record. In a software project, whenever you have concerns, you write tests to validate those concerns. That's how you prevent issues. You don't have to leave anything to chance. The tests will prove both correctness and help humans understand how things are working.

Answer (score 16):

Although using a business key (option 3) is the most commonly recommended approach ([Hibernate community wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode), "Java Persistence with Hibernate" p. 398), and this is what we mostly use, there's a Hibernate bug which breaks this for eager-fetched sets: [HHH-3799](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3799).  In this case, Hibernate can add an entity to a set before its fields are initialized.  I'm not sure why this bug hasn't gotten more attention, as it really makes the recommended business-key approach problematic.

I think the heart of the matter is that equals and hashCode should be based on immutable state (reference [Odersky et al.](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html)), and a Hibernate entity with Hibernate-managed primary key has *no* such immutable state.  The primary key is modified by Hibernate when a transient object becomes persistent.  The business key is also modified by Hibernate, when it hydrates an object in the process of being initialized.

That leaves only option 1, inheriting the java.lang.Object implementations based on object identity, or using an application-managed primary key as suggested by James Brundege in ["Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180506060716/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html) (already referenced by Stijn Geukens's answer) and by Lance Arlaus in ["Object Generation: A Better Approach to Hibernate Integration"](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30396).

The biggest problem with option 1 is that detached instances can't be compared with persistent instances using .equals().  But that's OK; the contract of equals and hashCode leaves it up to the developer to decide what equality means for each class.  So just let equals and hashCode inherit from Object.  If you need to compare a detached instance to a persistent instance, you can create a new method explicitly for that purpose, perhaps `boolean sameEntity` or `boolean dbEquivalent` or `boolean businessEquals`.

Answer (score 7):

[Jakarta Persistence 3.0, section 4.12](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a5735) writes:

> Two entities of the same abstract schema type are equal if and only if they have the same primary key value.

I see no reason why Java code should behave differently.

If the entity class is in a so called "transient" state, i.e. it's not yet persisted and it has no identifier, then the hashCode/equals methods can not return a value, they ought to blow up, ideally implicitly with a `NullPointerException` when the method attempts to traverse the ID. Either way, this will effectively stop application code from putting a non-managed entity into a hash-based data structure. In fact, why not go one step further and blow up if the class and identifier are equal, but other important attributes such as the `version` are unequal (`IllegalStateException`)! [Fail-fast](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf) in a deterministic way is always the preferred option.

Word of caution: Also document the blowing-up behavior. Documentation is important in and by itself, but it will hopefully also stop junior developers in the future to do something stupid with your code (they have this tendency to suppress NullPointerException where it happened and the last thing on their mind is side-effects lol).

Oh, and always use `getClass()` instead of `instanceof`. The equals-method requires symmetry. If `b` is equal to `a`, then `a` must be equal to `b`. With subclasses, `instanceof` breaks this relationship (`a` is *not* instance of `b`).

Although I personally always use `getClass()` even when implementing non-entity classes (the type *is* state, and so a subclass *adds state* even if the subclass is empty or only contains behavior), `instanceof` would've been fine only if the class is *final*. But entity classes must not be final ([§2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a18)) so we're really out of options here.

Some folks may not like `getClass()`, because of the persistence provider's proxy wrapping the object. This might have been a problem in the past, but it really shouldn't be. A provider not returning different proxy classes for different entities, well, I'd say that's not a very smart provider lol. Generally, we shouldn't solve a problem until there is a problem. And, it seems like Hibernate's own documentation doesn't even see it worthwhile mentioning. In fact, they elegantly use `getClass()` in their own examples ([see this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode)).

Lastly, if one has an entity subclass that is an entity, and the inheritance mapping strategy used is not the default ("single table"), but configured to be a "joined subtype", then the primary key in that subclass table *will be the same* as the superclass table. If the mapping strategy is "table per concrete class", then the primary key *may be the same* as in the superclass. An entity subclass is very likely to be adding state and therefore just as likely to be logically a different thing. But an equals implementation using `instanceof` can not necessarily and secondarily rely on the ID only, as we saw may be the same for different entities.

In my opinion, `instanceof` has no place at all in a non-final Java class, ever. This is especially true for persistent entities.

Comment: Even with a DB missing sequences (like Mysql), it's possible to simulate them (e.g., table hibernate_sequence). So you may always get an ID unique across tables. +++ But you don't need it. Calling `Object#getClass() ` is bad because of H. proxies. Calling `Hibernate.getClass(o)` helps, but the problem of equality of entities of different kinds remains. There's a solution using [canEqual](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html), a bit complicated, but usable. Agreed that usually it's not needed. +++ Throwing in eq/hc on null ID violates the contract, but it's very pragmatic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the answer. The one thing I wish to add here is that the statement "throwing in eq/hc on null ID violaes the contract" is wrong. It's objectively wrong because, well, it's simply not part of the contract. Not that it matters for the truthfulness, but I'd just like to add that [others agree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15152484/1268003).

Comment: I think your `getClass()` over `instanceof` is incorrect in the context of a provided Identity attribute. IOW, given the very first quoted assertion with you which you start your answer, the typing/subtyping is to be essentially ignored for the same reason the other fields outside the provided identity attribute. IOW, the entire philosophy pivots on the identity anchored in an "independent" value.

Comment: And even if you still want the `getClasss()` check, I would recommend this more modern fluent functional expression approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75402885/501113

Comment: And here's my own answer/solution to OP's question around when I choose option 2. And in that pattern, I use the `instanceof` (effectively handles `null` check). The `getClass()` line is commented out as it failed for JPA/Hibernate proxies. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091598/501113

Comment: `getClass()` is the only valid alternative for non-final classes. There's really no "context" to be bothered with? I would be happy if you could detail what problem exactly, you had with Hibernate proxies. I've never experienced any problems myself, and apparently not Hibernate either, which are using `getClass()` in their documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Andrew's answer. We do the same thing in our application but instead of storing UUIDs as VARCHAR/CHAR, we split it into two long values. See UUID.getLeastSignificantBits() and UUID.getMostSignificantBits().

One more thing to consider, is that calls to UUID.randomUUID() are pretty slow, so you might want to look into lazily generating the UUID only when needed, such as during persistence or calls to equals()/hashCode()

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractJpaEntity extends AbstractMutable implements Identifiable, Modifiable {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
    private int                 version             = 0;

    @Column(name = "uuid_least_sig_bits")
    private long                uuidLeastSigBits    = 0;

    @Column(name = "uuid_most_sig_bits")
    private long                uuidMostSigBits     = 0;

    private transient int       hashCode            = 0;

    public AbstractJpaEntity() {
        //
    }

    public abstract Integer getId();

    public abstract void setId(final Integer id);

    public boolean isPersisted() {
        return getId() != null;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    //calling UUID.randomUUID() is pretty expensive, 
    //so this is to lazily initialize uuid bits.
    private void initUUID() {
        final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        uuidLeastSigBits = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
        uuidMostSigBits = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    }

    public long getUuidLeastSigBits() {
        //its safe to assume uuidMostSigBits of a valid UUID is never zero
        if (uuidMostSigBits == 0) {
            initUUID();
        }
        return uuidLeastSigBits;
    }

    public long getUuidMostSigBits() {
        //its safe to assume uuidMostSigBits of a valid UUID is never zero
        if (uuidMostSigBits == 0) {
            initUUID();
        }
        return uuidMostSigBits;
    }

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return new UUID(getUuidMostSigBits(), getUuidLeastSigBits());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (hashCode == 0) {
            hashCode = (int) (getUuidMostSigBits() >> 32 ^ getUuidMostSigBits() ^ getUuidLeastSigBits() >> 32 ^ getUuidLeastSigBits());
        }
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof AbstractJpaEntity)) {
            return false;
        }
        //UUID guarantees a pretty good uniqueness factor across distributed systems, so we can safely
        //dismiss getClass().equals(obj.getClass()) here since the chance of two different objects (even 
        //if they have different types) having the same UUID is astronomical
        final AbstractJpaEntity entity = (AbstractJpaEntity) obj;
        return getUuidMostSigBits() == entity.getUuidMostSigBits() && getUuidLeastSigBits() == entity.getUuidLeastSigBits();
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        // make sure the uuid is set before persisting
        getUuidLeastSigBits();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, actually if you override equals()/hashCode() then you have to generate UUID for every entity anyway (I assume that you want to persist every entity you create in your code). You do it only once - before storing it to a database for the first time. After that UUID is just loaded by Persistence Provider. Thus I don't see th point of doing it lazily.

Comment: I up-voted your answer because I really like your other ideas: storing UUID as a pair of numbers in the database and not casting to a particular type inside the equals() method - that one is really neat! I'll definitely use these two tricks in future.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. The reason for lazily initializing the UUID was in our app we create a lot of Entities that never get put in a HashMap or persisted. So we saw 100x drop in performance when we were creating the object (100,000s of them). So we only init the UUID if it's needed. I just wish there was good support in MySql for 128 bit numbers so we could just use the UUID for id too and don't care about the auto_increment.

Comment: Oh, I see. In my case we don't even declare UUID field if corresponding entity is not going to be put in collections. The drawback is that sometimes we have to add it because later it turns out that we actually need to put them in collections. This happens sometimes during development but fortunately never happened to us after initial deployment to a customer so it wasn't a big deal. If that would happen after the system went live we would need a db migration. Lazy UUID are very helpful in such situations.

Comment: Maybe you should also try the faster UUID generator Adam suggested in his answer if performance is a critical issue in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are obviously already very informative answers here but I will tell you what we do.

We do nothing (ie do not override).

If we do need equals/hashcode to work for collections we use UUIDs.
You just create the UUID in the constructor. We use http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome for UUID. UUID is a little more expensive CPU wise but is cheap compared to serialization and db access.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider the following approach based on predefined type identifier and the ID.

The specific assumptions for JPA:

- entities of the same "type" and the same non-null ID are considered equal
- non-persisted entities (assuming no ID) are never equal to other entities

The abstract entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPersistable<K extends Serializable> {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private K id;

  @Transient
  private final String kind;

  public AbstractPersistable(final String kind) {
    this.kind = requireNonNull(kind, "Entity kind cannot be null");
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof AbstractPersistable)) return false;
    final AbstractPersistable<?> that = (AbstractPersistable<?>) obj;
    return null != this.id
        && Objects.equals(this.id, that.id)
        && Objects.equals(this.kind, that.kind);
  }

  @Override
  public final int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(kind, id);
  }

  public K getId() {
    return id;
  }

  protected void setId(final K id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Concrete entity example:

```
static class Foo extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
  public Foo() {
    super("Foo");
  }
}
```

Test example:

```
@Test
public void test_EqualsAndHashcode_GivenSubclass() {
  // Check contract
  EqualsVerifier.forClass(Foo.class)
    .suppress(Warning.NONFINAL_FIELDS, Warning.TRANSIENT_FIELDS)
    .withOnlyTheseFields("id", "kind")
    .withNonnullFields("id", "kind")
    .verify();
  // Ensure new objects are not equal
  assertNotEquals(new Foo(), new Foo());
}
```

Main advantages here:

- simplicity
- ensures subclasses provide type identity
- predicted behavior with proxied classes

Disadvantages:

- Requires each entity to call `super()`

Notes:

- Needs attention when using inheritance. E.g. instance equality of `class A` and `class B extends A` may depend on concrete details of the application.
- Ideally, use a business key as the ID

Looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used option 1 in the past because I was aware of these discussions and thought it was better to do nothing until I knew the right thing to do. Those systems are all still running successfully.

However, next time I may try option 2 - using the database generated Id.

Hashcode and equals will throw IllegalStateException if the id is not set.

This will prevent subtle errors involving unsaved entities from appearing unexpectedly.

What do people think of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Business keys approach doesn't suit for us. We use DB generated **ID**, temporary transient **tempId** and **override** equal()/hashcode() to solve the dilemma. All entities are descendants of Entity. Pros:

1. No extra fields in DB
2. No extra coding in descendants entities, one approach for all
3. No performance issues (like with UUID), DB Id generation
4. No problem with Hashmaps (don't need to keep in mind the use of equal & etc.)
5. Hashcode of new entity doesn't changed in time even after persisting

Cons:

1. There are may be problems with serializing and deserializing not persisted entities
2. Hashcode of the saved entity may change after reloading from DB
3. Not persisted objects considered always different (maybe this is right?)
4. What else?

Look at our code:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Transient
    private Long tempId;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setTempId(Long tempId) {
        this.tempId = tempId;
    }

    // Fix Id on first call from equal() or hashCode()
    private Long getTempId() {
        if (tempId == null)
            // if we have id already, use it, else use 0
            setTempId(getId() == null ? 0 : getId());
        return tempId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (super.equals(obj))
            return true;
        // take proxied object into account
        if (obj == null || !Hibernate.getClass(obj).equals(this.getClass()))
            return false;
        Entity o = (Entity) obj;
        return getTempId() != 0 && o.getTempId() != 0 && getTempId().equals(o.getTempId());
    }

    // hash doesn't change in time
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getTempId() == 0 ? super.hashCode() : getTempId().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO you have 3 options for implementing equals/hashCode

- Use an application generated identity i.e. a UUID
- Implement it based on a business key
- Implement it based on the primary key

**Using an application generated identity is the easiest approach, but comes with a few downsides**

- Joins are slower when using it as PK because 128 Bit is simply bigger than 32 or 64 Bit
- "Debugging is harder" because checking with your own eyes wether some data is correct is pretty hard

If you can work with these *downsides*, just use this approach.

To overcome the join issue one could be using the UUID as natural key and a sequence value as primary key, but then you might still run into the equals/hashCode implementation problems in compositional child entities that have embedded ids since you will want to join based on the primary key. Using the natural key in child entities id and the primary key for referring to the parent is a good compromise.

```
@Entity class Parent {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
  @NaturalId UUID uuid;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent") Set<Child> children;
  // equals/hashCode based on uuid
}

@Entity class Child {
  @EmbeddedId ChildId id;
  @ManyToOne Parent parent;

  @Embeddable class ChildId {
    UUID parentUuid;
    UUID childUuid;
    // equals/hashCode based on parentUuid and childUuid
  }
  // equals/hashCode based on id
}
```

IMO this is the cleanest approach as it will avoid all downsides and at the same time provide you a value(the UUID) that you can share with external systems without exposing system internals.

**Implement it based on a business key if you can expect that from a user is a nice idea, but comes with a few downsides as well**

Most of the time this business key will be some kind of *code* that the user provides and less often a composite of multiple attributes.

- Joins are slower because joining based on variable length text is simply slow. Some DBMS might even have problems creating an index if the key exceeds a certain length.
- In my experience, business keys tend to change which will require cascading updates to objects referring to it. This is impossible if external systems refer to it

IMO you shouldn't implement or work with a business key exclusively. It's a nice add-on i.e. users can quickly search by that business key, but the system shouldn't rely on it for operating.

**Implement it based on the primary key has it's problems, but maybe it's not such a big deal**

If you need to expose ids to external system, use the UUID approach I suggested. If you don't, you could still use the UUID approach but you don't have to.
The problem of using a DBMS generated id in equals/hashCode stems from the fact that the object might have been added to hash based collections before assigning the id.

The obvious way to get around this is to simply not add the object to hash based collections before assigning the id. I understand that this is not always possible because you might want deduplication before assigning the id already. To still be able to use the hash based collections, you simply have to rebuild the collections after assigning the id.

You could do something like this:

```
@Entity class Parent {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent") Set<Child> children;
  // equals/hashCode based on id
}

@Entity class Child {
  @EmbeddedId ChildId id;
  @ManyToOne Parent parent;

  @PrePersist void postPersist() {
    parent.children.remove(this);
  }
  @PostPersist void postPersist() {
    parent.children.add(this);
  }

  @Embeddable class ChildId {
    Long parentId;
    @GeneratedValue Long childId;
    // equals/hashCode based on parentId and childId
  }
  // equals/hashCode based on id
}
```

I haven't tested the exact approach myself, so I'm not sure how changing collections in pre- and post-persist events works but the idea is:

- Temporarily Remove the object from hash based collections
- Persist it
- Re-add the object to the hash based collections

Another way of solving this is to simply rebuild all your hash based models after an update/persist.

In the end, it's up to you. I personally use the sequence based approach most of the time and only use the UUID approach if I need to expose an identifier to external systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in every IT system that uses Java and JPA. The pain point extends beyond implementing equals() and hashCode(), it affects how an organization refer to an entity and how its clients refer to the same entity. I've seen enough pain of not having a business key to the point that I wrote [my own blog](http://geeksrandomthoughts.blogspot.com/2014/10/my-take-on-dont-let-hibernate-steal.html) to express my view.

In short: use a short, human readable, sequential ID with meaningful prefixes as business key that's generated without any dependency on any storage other than RAM. Twitter's [Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake) is a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

I using a class EntityBase and inherited to all my entities of JPA and this it works very good to me.

```
/**
 * @author marcos.oliveira
 */
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBase<TId extends Serializable> implements Serializable{
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected TId id;



    public TId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(TId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (super.hashCode() * 907) + Objects.hashCode(getId());//this.getId().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " [Id=" + id + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        EntityBase entity = (EntityBase) obj;
        if (entity.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, entity.id);
    }
}
```

Reference: https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the OPs two questions:

> Did I miss an option and/or pro/con point?

I think you covered all the options/context.

> What option did you choose and why?

I chose OP's option 2 - Override them, based on the primary key

Below is the pattern I'm using at and beyond Java 16 where JPA (i.e. the database) is generating the `marketId` when first saved (INSERTED) into its repository.

**The key difference:** Keeping `equals` and `hashCode` consistent regarding the two states (`null` and `not null`) of the `marketId`.

IOW, they are consistent with each other per their stated contracts. The other solutions I've seen allow `equals` to change when `marketId` changes from `null` to non-`null`, and don't have `hashCode` also change at the same time and in the same way. This breaks the contract.

The key part of this is within `hashCode` itself, in that it explicitly avoids hashing the `null` value, which always results in
a hash value of 0.

`Objects.hash(null)` can cause bad performance in both `Set` and/or as a `Map` key if many entities haven't yet been INSERTed.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  return (o == this) ||
      ((o instanceof Market that)
          //&& (this.getClass() == that.getClass())
          && ((this.marketId != null) && (that.marketId != null))
          && (this.marketId.intValue() == that.marketId.intValue()));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return
      this.marketId == null
          ? super.hashCode()
          : Objects.hash(marketId);
}
```

For more details about the `equals` pattern above, please see this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75402885/501113).

**Note:** Because of how JPA/Hibernate can handle proxies, the line `&& (this.getClass() == that.getClass())` doesn't work the way intended and is commented out.

**CAVEAT:** This assumes that the `marketId` is `null` within the JPA entity prior to being persisted (INSERTed) the first time. And that the instance is modified (i.e. mutated) during the persistence operation.

Any use of a `Market` entity instance with a `null` `marketId` field within an existing `Set` or as a `Map` key must be "reinitialized" before further use.

The `Set` (or `Map`) behavior has become undefined due to the entity's mutation by the JPA during that initial save (INSERT). The values returned by both `equals` and `hashCode` will have changed.

Hence, the requirement is to stop using any current collection instances that depend upon coherent and consistent `equals` and `hashCode` (i.e. `Set` and `Map`) containing the newly persisted entities.

And to explicitly regenerate any collections to correctly incorporate the new non-null `marketId` value injected by the JPA framework.

Answer (score -1):

If UUID is the answer for many people, why don't we just use factory methods from business layer to create the entities and assign primary key at creation time?

for example:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyCarFacade {
  public Car createCar(){
    Car car = new Car();
    em.persist(car);
    return car;
  }
}
```

this way we would get a default primary key for the entity from the persistence provider, and our hashCode() and equals() functions could rely on that.

We could also declare the Car's constructors protected and then use reflection in our business method to access them. This way developers would not be intent on instantiate Car with new, but through factory method.

How'bout that?

Comment: An approach that works great if you're willing to take the performance hit both of generating the guid when doing a database lookup.

Comment: What about unit testing Car ? In this case you need a database connection for testing ? Also, your domain objects should not depend on persistance.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to answer this question myself and was never totally happy with found solutions until i read this post and especially DREW one. I liked the way he lazy created UUID and optimally stored it.

But I wanted to add even more flexibility, ie lazy create UUID ONLY when hashCode()/equals() is accessed before first persistence of the entity with each solution's advantages :

- equals() means "object refers to the same logical entity"
- use database ID as much as possible because why would I do the work twice (performance concern)
- prevent problem while accessing hashCode()/equals() on not yet persisted entity and keep the same behaviour after it is indeed persisted

I would really apreciate feedback on my mixed-solution below

> ```
> public class MyEntity { 
>
>     @Id()
>     @Column(name = "ID", length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true)
>     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
>     private Long id = null;
>
>     @Transient private UUID uuid = null;
>
>     @Column(name = "UUID_MOST", nullable = true, unique = false, updatable = false)
>     private Long uuidMostSignificantBits = null;
>     @Column(name = "UUID_LEAST", nullable = true, unique = false, updatable = false)
>     private Long uuidLeastSignificantBits = null;
>
>     @Override
>     public final int hashCode() {
>         return this.getUuid().hashCode();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public final boolean equals(Object toBeCompared) {
>         if(this == toBeCompared) {
>             return true;
>         }
>         if(toBeCompared == null) {
>             return false;
>         }
>         if(!this.getClass().isInstance(toBeCompared)) {
>             return false;
>         }
>         return this.getUuid().equals(((MyEntity)toBeCompared).getUuid());
>     }
>
>     public final UUID getUuid() {
>         // UUID already accessed on this physical object
>         if(this.uuid != null) {
>             return this.uuid;
>         }
>         // UUID one day generated on this entity before it was persisted
>         if(this.uuidMostSignificantBits != null) {
>             this.uuid = new UUID(this.uuidMostSignificantBits, this.uuidLeastSignificantBits);
>         // UUID never generated on this entity before it was persisted
>         } else if(this.getId() != null) {
>             this.uuid = new UUID(this.getId(), this.getId());
>         // UUID never accessed on this not yet persisted entity
>         } else {
>             this.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
>         }
>         return this.uuid; 
>     }
>
>     private void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
>         if(uuid == null) {
>             return;
>         }
>         // For the one hypothetical case where generated UUID could colude with UUID build from IDs
>         if(uuid.getMostSignificantBits() == uuid.getLeastSignificantBits()) {
>             throw new Exception("UUID: " + this.getUuid() + " format is only for internal use");
>         }
>         this.uuidMostSignificantBits = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
>         this.uuidLeastSignificantBits = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
>         this.uuid = uuid;
>     }
> ```

Comment: what do you mean by "UUID one day generated on this entity before i was persisted" ? could you please give an example for this case ?

Comment: could you use assigned generationtype? why is identity generationtype need? does it have some advantage over assigned?

Comment: what happens if you 1) make a new MyEntity, 2) put it into a list, 3) then save it to database then 4) you load that entity back from DB and 5) try to see if the loaded instance is in the list. My guess is that it wont't be even though it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your first comments that showed me I wasn't as clear as I should.   Firstly, "UUID one day generated on this entity before i was persisted" was a typo ... "before IT was persisted" should have been read instead. For the other remarks, I'll edit my post soon to try to explain better my solution.

Comment: This solution appears to be unsafe in the presence of concurrency/multi-threading. IOW, there is at least one latent race-condition, if not several. Given a JPA entity cannot be market `final` and cannot be "effectively immutable", this solution needs to be enhanced to ensure concurrency/multi-threading coherence.

Answer (score -1):

In practice it seems, that Option 2 (Primary key) is most frequently used.
Natural and IMMUTABLE business key is seldom thing, creating and supporting synthetic keys are too heavy to solve situations, which are probably never happened.
Have a look at [spring-data-jpa AbstractPersistable](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.java) implementation (the only thing: [for Hibernate  implementation use `Hibernate.getClass`](https://blog.oio.de/2010/09/24/instanceof-fails-with-hibernate-lazy-loading-and-entity-class-hierarchy/)).

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (null == obj) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!getClass().equals(ClassUtils.getUserClass(obj))) {
        return false;
    }
    AbstractPersistable<?> that = (AbstractPersistable<?>) obj;
    return null == this.getId() ? false : this.getId().equals(that.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 17;
    hashCode += null == getId() ? 0 : getId().hashCode() * 31;
    return hashCode;
}
```

Just aware of manipulating new objects in HashSet/HashMap.
In opposite, the Option 1 (remain `Object` implementation) is broken just after `merge`, that is very common situation.

If you have no business key and have a REAL needs to manipulate new entity in hash structure, override `hashCode` to constant, as [Vlad Mihalcea advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma/26826084#26826084).

Answer (score -2):

Below is a **simple** (and tested) solution for Scala.

- Note that this solution does not fit into any of the 3 categories
  given in the question.
- All my Entities are subclasses of the UUIDEntity so I follow the
  don't-repeat-yourself (DRY) principle.
- If needed the UUID generation can be made more precise (by using more
  pseudo-random numbers).

Scala Code:

```
import javax.persistence._
import scala.util.Random

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class UUIDEntity {
  @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  var id:java.lang.Long=null
  var uuid:java.lang.Long=Random.nextLong()
  override def equals(o:Any):Boolean= 
    o match{
      case o : UUIDEntity => o.uuid==uuid
      case _ => false
    }
  override def hashCode() = uuid.hashCode()
}
```