# Did I implement equals and hashCode correctly using Google Guava?

Tags: java, equals, guava, hashcode

I am using hibernate and need to override equals and hashCode(). I chose to use google-guava's equals and hashCode helpers.

I wanted to know if I am missing something here.

I have get/set methods for **idImage** and **filePath**.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGE")
public class ImageEntity {
    private Integer idImage;
    private String filePath;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getFilePath());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if(obj == this) return true;
        if(obj == null) return false;

        if(obj instanceof ImageEntity){
            final ImageEntity otherImage = (ImageEntity) obj;
            return Objects.equal(getFilePath(), otherImage.getFilePath());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ran into inheritance and have a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885773/how-do-i-correctly-override-equals-for-inheritance-in-java)

Comment: It looks right... are you getting any errors/unwanted behavior with it?

Comment: @NimChimpsky idImage is the id mapping to auto increment Primary Key in database (using hibernate).

Comment: @Marcelo No, not as of now. everything works great. I just wanted to know if I missed on anything.

Comment: For anyone else, who comes here wandering: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with the `instanceof` operator is that it works taking into account polymorphism, if I may say so.

Let's say, for example, that you do this:

```
public class AdvancedImageEntity extends ImageEntity
{
    //some code here
}
```

and then you do this:

```
ImageEntity ie = new ImageEntity ();
AdvancedImageEntity advanced_ie = new AdvancedImageEntity ();

boolean this_will_be_true = ie.equals (advanced_ie);
```

As the name suggests, that `equals` call will return true, because of the `instanceof` operator.

I know this sounds like basic stuff and most people know it, but it's  SOOOO damn easy to forget it. Now, if you want that behaviour, then it's fine, you implemented `equals` correctly. But if you consider that an `ImageEntity` object must not be equal to an (hypothetical) `AdvancedImageEntity` object, then either declare `ImageEntity` to be `final` OR forget about `instanceof` and implement your `equals` method like this:

```
@Override public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    if(obj == this) return true;
    if(obj == null) return false;

    if (getClass ().equals (obj.getClass ()))
    {
        final ImageEntity otherImage = (ImageEntity) obj;

        return Object.equals (getFilePath(), otherImage.getFilePath());
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will check the object's true type, no matter what type the reference is. If the `obj` parameter is an instance of a subclass, it would "slip" by `instanceof`. But `getClass` is a lot more strict and won't allow it.

PS: I'm not saying that `instanceof` is bad and should not be used. I'm just saying that you must be aware of this particular situation and decide whether to use it taking this into account.

Comment: Better yet--don't subclass DTOs

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object; roughly equivalent to value objects, if you're more familiar with that term. In this case, you'd want to favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: I think first two `if` statements in `equals` are redundant because the Guava's `Object#equals` do those.

Comment: @Sangdol The `equals` method is overriden. There is no call anywhere to `super.equals()`. This means that whatever is going on in `Object#equals` is irrelevant (because it's never executed).

Comment: Oh, I misread your code. I thought you used Guava's `Objects#equal`. Check [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r09/com/google/common/base/Objects.java#Objects.equal%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Comment: @Sangdol I understand now what you meant. I think I should edit my answer though... I totally forgot about `obj instanceof A` where `A` is an interface, not a class. Maybe later tonight :) .

Comment: What's the purpose of comparing class names rather than classes?

Comment: @DaveNewton Hmmm, I guess I thought that either works. But actually... what if both classes have the same name but are in different packages ? You probably have a point here, let me look into it :) .

Comment: `getName` returns the FQN, AFAIK. It just seems redundant.

Comment: "Don't subclass DTOs" may not be possible with tools like Hibernate, which subclass your model objects with proxies to implement features like lazy loading.

Answer (score 13):

You could actually use the [Guava EqualsTester](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/EqualsTester.java) to test your equals and hashCode implementation:

```
new EqualsTester()
     .addEqualityGroup("hello", "h" + "ello")
     .addEqualityGroup("world", "wor" + "ld")
     .addEqualityGroup(2, 1 + 1)
     .testEquals();
```

It's in the guava testlib.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Minor change to your implementation:

```
@Override public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if(obj == this) return true;
    return obj instanceof ImageEntity &&
        Objects.equal(getFilePath(), ((ImageEntity) obj).getFilePath());
}
```

Comment: @David Don't understand your argument.

Comment: @David I'd expect that this fails, which is obviously correct in this example.

Answer (score 3):

Its fine as is. Although instanceof makes the null check unnessary.

Also, I think its fine to use auto generated id's, although this is [very](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7886331/106261) [debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7579404/106261).

Comment: I agree on the redundancy of the null check. Just remove it, and it'll be ok.

Comment: Also, you could just go ahead and use `getFilePath().hashCode()` instead of `Objects.hashCode(getFilePath())`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - That will fail if `getFilePath()` can return `null`. It's not mentioned in the docs, but I suspect that `Objects.hashCode()` which calls `Arrays.hashCode()` handles `null` values safely.

Comment: Perhaps, although `getFilePath()` returning null _probably_ reflects a bug. ;)