# Java inheritance in DTOs

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class A with these properties:

```
class A {

String a;
String b;
.....
List<C> myList;
}
```

I want a class Aext that will extend A and will also "extend" myList properties,meaning:

```
class Aext extends A {

String x;
.....
List<Cext> myList;
....
}
```

where:

```
class Cext extends C {
 ......
}
```

But I cannot have a member in subclass with same name as superclass i.e : myList. Name must not be changed. I want an "extended" myList that has the properties of C plus the properties of Cext. A and B are DTOs so I want to 
sometimes return B as an "enriched" version of A without changing names,types etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics to the rescue.

```
class A<T extends C> {

protected String a;
protected String b;
.....
protected List<T> myList;
}
```

Now `myList` has elements of the type `T` which extends `C`.

When you subclass `A` with `Aext` you can specify `Cext` as the type of the elements for `myList`.

```
class Aext extends A<Cext> {

String x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have generics. Use them.

```
class A<T extends C> {
String a;
String b;
.....
List<T> myList;
}

class Aext extends A<Cext> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In inheritance is discouraged for DTOs especially if you're going to instantiate objects from different stages in the inheritance hierarchy.

The reason is the relationship between `equals()` and `hashcode()`.
[how do I correctly override equals for inheritance in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885773/how-do-i-correctly-override-equals-for-inheritance-in-java)