# upcasting confusion while checking instanceof

Tags: java, upcasting

```
class Animal
{

}

    class Dog extends Animal
    {

    }

    class main
    {
      public static void main(String args[])
    Animal g= new Dog();
    System.out.println(g instanceof Dog);      // 1st case

    System.out.println(g instanceof Animal);   // 2nd case

}
```

QUESTION: why the output is true in both cases ?

Comment: Shouldn't Dog extend Animal, though?

Comment: I added `extends Animal`, the OP probably just forgot it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the object that is referenced, at run-time, by local variable `g` is of type `Dog` (and thus also an `Animal`, because `Dog extends Animal`, though that's missing from your example).

Answer (score 4):

This is polymorphism in action. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) and [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31).

If you want to avoid this behaviour, use `getClass()` instead of `instanceof`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257211/did-i-implement-equals-and-hashcode-correctly-using-google-guava/9258977#9258977) for an example.

Comment: though your example does not show your usage, be wary anytime you use this kind of construct on a class hierarchy.  If you find yourself consistently checking the type in an if statement, you might want to consider putting that behavior inside a method which can be implemented differentl for each subclass.