# safely using JPA merge() with relationships (eclipselink, glassfish 3.1)

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb, eclipselink

A while back on IRC I was told to create copied subLists when merging an entity's relationships in my EJB update method.  My question is:  is this really necessary?

Here's my code ...

(in CtCaseEJB)

```
  public CtCase update( CtCase pCase )
  {
    CtCase aCtCase = em.merge( pCase );
    ...
    List<CtCaseTest> aCaseTestList = pCase.getCaseTests();               
    List<CtCaseTest> aNewCaseTestList = new ArrayList<CtCaseTest>();
    for( CtCaseTest aCaseTest : aCaseTestList )
    {
        aCaseTest = em.merge( aCaseTest );
        aNewCaseTestList.add( aCaseTest );
    }
    aCtCase.setCaseTests( aNewCaseTestList );
    ...
    return aCtCase;
 }
```

The relationship is defined as:

(in CtCase)

```
private List<CtCaseTest> mCaseTests = new ArrayList<CtCaseTest>();

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "ctCase", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH } )
@OrderBy( "rank" )
public List<CtCaseTest> getCaseTests()
{
    return mCaseTests;
}

public void setCaseTests( List<CtCaseTest> pCaseTests )
{
    mCaseTests = pCaseTests;
}
```

This is how I'm currently doing it, though I'm getting some very occassional wonky behavior (doubled lists are getting created somehow).

My question is:  why can't I add CascadeType.MERGE and simply do this in CtCaseEJB ...

```
  public CtCase update( CtCase pCase )
  {
    return em.merge( pCase );
  }
```

Why the need for manually merging relationships in JPA/EJB?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manually merge. Do add `CascadeType.MERGE`.
It is important that your `equals()` and `hashcode()` is implemented properly for this to work.
My best guess to why you are seeing "wonky" behaviour, doubling of the list/etc, is that there is something wrong with the `equals()` and/or `hashcode()`.

A side point: I would make a copy of the provided list in `setTestCase()`, to avoid future problems.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying as general principle to always use copy constructors in setList() methods in JPA?  Or is this instance specific.

Comment: Is it sufficient for equals() and hashcode() to use the entities unique ID (if it exists), with possibly not unique value munging (if not yet)?

Comment: I prefer it that way, but it is a much discussed and to large extent unresolved problem-area. And people smarter than me would prefer other solutions. `equals` and `hashcode` in ORM frameworks in general and in JPA specifically is complicated. An internet search with relevant terms should provide some text material.

Comment: such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma