# Are exceptions in hashCode and equals methods allowed and acceptable in Java?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, equals, hashcode

Some classes filled by frameworks (like beans). So you can't guaranty that all fields set.

Look to example: classes marked as `@Entity` usually have `Integer id` field. `hashCode` can be written as:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}
```

but defensive code may look like:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) ? id.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Do I need write checks for null or surround code with `try { ... } catch (Exception e)` in `hashCode` and `equals` functions?

I have no arguments for defencive coding is such case because it hide putting inconsistent objects to collections and lead to late errors. Am I wrong in this position?

**UPDATE** I wrote such code:

```
import java.util.*;

class ExceptionInHashcode {

    String name;

    ExceptionInHashcode() { }
    ExceptionInHashcode(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public int hashCode() {
        // throw new IllegalStateException("xxx");
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hashtable list = new Hashtable();
        list.put(new ExceptionInHashcode("ok"), 1);
        list.put(new ExceptionInHashcode(), 2); // fail
        System.out.println("list.size(): " + list.size());
    }
}
```

and run it:

```
java -classpath . ExceptionInHashcode
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ExceptionInHashcode.hashCode(ExceptionInHashcode.java:12)
        at java.util.Hashtable.hash(Hashtable.java:262)
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:547)
        at ExceptionInHashcode.main(ExceptionInHashcode.java:18)
```

I think that I can find error early instead of returning zero if object is in wrong state...

Comment: Your hashCode implementation breaks the [`Object#hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) contract: *Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.*

Comment: If you are to throw an exception I would be more inclined to throw an `IllegalStateException` rather than just let the `NullPointerException` bubble up. To me a `NullPointerException` in someone else's code smells of a bug, but an `IllegalStateException` tells me "you're not allowed to do that (yet), *by design*".

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Information used by the equals comparison *would* change if the id is changed though. Are you talking about the number returned, or the exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet about the number returned, since this implementation would return the `id.hashCode()` sometimes and `0` in others.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: But so long as `id` is also used in `equals`, it doesn't violate the contract. What *exact* scenario are you considering which would break the contract, assuming that `equals` *does* use `id`?

Comment: @JonSkeet so I can have `int x = entity.hashCode(); //0... entity.setId(someClassInstance.createId()); int y = entity.hashCode; if (x != y) { System.out.println("this is fine!"); }` assuming that `someClassInstance.createId()` would return a non-null id for the entity, and this would be good? By the way, I understand it could be legal.

Comment: Yes, that's fine - and explicitly covered in the contract you stated: "the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, **provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified**". The information used in equals comparisons has been modified, so it's fine for the hash code to change.

Comment: @JonSkeet what about *Whenever it is invoked **on the same object more than once** during an execution of a Java application* part before the text you pulled out?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Assuming that `equals` uses `id` to do a comparison, by changing the `id` you have semantically changed the object to be a different one, even though the physical object in memory is the same. IMHO, the problem really comes from being able to change `id` in the first place.

Comment: @lc. so if I use this `Entity` as key for a `Map` and I change the `id` attribute value after setting the same `Entity` instance as key in the `Map`, doesn't that make the `Map` to have an odd behavior?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh yeah, it does. That's why I said the problem comes from being able to change `id` after it's been set.

Comment: @lc. then this is not a valid implementation for `hashCode` =\ , it's legal but not valid.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yes, it *is*. It *doesn't* violate the rules for `hashCode`. If you change the `id` after putting it into the map, *you're* violating the rules for what you do with keys.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That's still covered by the "provided no information..." clause which you're completely ignoring. Basically, if you change information used by `equals` between two calls to `hashCode`, all bets are off.

Comment: @JonSkeet after searching this on the net, I found that I didn't understand the whole concept. IMO [this blog entry](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) points an interesting resource that explains this. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the answer is "it depends".

- If you should *never* see instances of the class with `null` for that field, then it is reasonable to allow an NPE to be thrown.  The NPE indicates a bug; i.e. a situation where your informal invariant is broken.
- If there are circumstances where an instance with a `null` could reasonably expected, then you should deal with the `null` case without throwing an exception.

---

In this particular case, you are apparently dealing with objects where the `id` field can be null if the object hasn't been persisted yet.  This presents a tricky problem:

- If you don't allow `null` for the `id`, then you have to be careful not to put non-persistent objects into a hash table.
- If you do allow `null` for the `id`, then you have the problem that if you add an object to a hash table and THEN persist it, the `hashcode` may change leading to breakage of the hash table.  So, now you need to defend against THAT ... by memoising the object's hashcode value in a transient field.  And roughly the same problem occurs with `equals`.  If equality changes when an object is persisted, then you had better not mix persisted and non-persisted keys in the same hash table.

Taking all of that into account, I'd advise to either throw that NPE, or not use the `id` fields in `equals` / `hashcode`.

Comment: Can only agree with all of what you said, except the first sentence lol. The answer to the _question_ isn't really "it depends"? Because, well... throwing an exception is allowed and is accepted. So the answer is "yes"? Hmm..., perhaps this is splitting hairs hahaha. Thank you Stephen for your awesome answer! I have a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382764/1268003).

Comment: Yes.  You are splitting hairs.  The question asked if it was "acceptable" ... not "accepted".   I am not talking about acceptable by the Java compiler.  (Of course it is acceptable by the compiler.  That is obvious!) I am talking about acceptable by the people who are going to review the OP's code.  People who might say "but `null` is an allowable value for field `x` and your `hashCode` and `equals` methods should not crap out".

Answer (score 8):

I would personally check for nullity and make the methods always return with no exceptions.

While runtime exceptions often aren't documented and can be thrown anywhere, I think it would be generally poor for them to be thrown by `equals` and `hashCode`. On the one hand, I can definitely see your point about being put in maps before being fully populated... but on the other hand it's hard to really know where `equals` will be called.

As lc says in comments, if you really want to throw an exception, it would be much better to throw an `IllegalStateException` to make it crystal clear that this was deliberate, than to let a `NullReferenceException` be thrown "by default" which makes it look like you just didn't think about the null scenario.

Comment: I agree, that `IllegalStateException` will be most applicable here.

Comment: I would personally rarely check for null, unless I am validating an argument the branch didn't traverse but according to the method contract I am supposed to throw NPE. And yeah, this is prolly the only exception. NPE is a God-given gift to us, if only we allow the code to blow up _when_ and exactly _where_ null became a problem. No ID = NPE. I would, however, use `IllegalStateException` for other aspects, such as a matching ID but not a matching `version` (see [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382764/1268003)).

Answer (score 2):

For validating the state of the object you should use [Bean validation framework](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) to make sure the state of the object is valid.

**No** hashcode and equals method should **not throw** Exceptions.

`equals` method **must** have checks for nullity. And when the object is created it is creators responsibility to make sure that the object is in valid state, so `hashCode` would never have to throw an exception. For that bean validation can be used. IMO.

**UPDATE**: As you are using bean frameworks which create beans for you, you have to rely on bean validation. But otherwise it MUST be the responsibility of the `Factory` that creates the object to make sure that **only a valid instance is created**.

Answer (score 1):

You never want a null pointer exception in your code. **Never**. Especially in functions heavily-used outside your own code. `hashcode` `equals` `toString` should never throw exceptions.

BTW: you can always just return id as the hashcode.

Comment: He can't returm 'id' as thee hashCode if 'id' is a object with its own hashCode() method, which it clearly is.

Comment: @EP the id is an Integer, as stated in the post. If the object is not null it's value can be returned and it will be a valid hashCode fulfilling all hashCode requirements.