# Spring Boot: ManyToOne relation with @JoinColumn keeps the foreign key null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, orm, mapping

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

followed the same approach for creating oneToMany & ManyToOne relation mapping.

Even though used the @JoinColumn in owning side entity, as per "baeldung" example in the "email entity" but it keeps the foreign key as null.

When I used the @JoinColumn in parent entity i.e. as per in above example in "Employee" entity, then it worked.

but what's the reason behind this behavior of relation mapping ? why this example approach is incorrect ?

Here is my code repo link : https://github.com/TamtePrathamesh/sb_mapping
between 'User' & 'mobile' while keeping oneToMany/ManyToOne mapping the mobile table not maintaining  the foreign key the entry comes as "NULL".
[Mobile Mapping Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5I3E.png)

Comment: I don't think the problem you are having is very clear. Maybe you  could show us how you mapped the our entities, and the exact error you are having?

Comment: I have attached the code repo link can you please check the code.

Comment: In github code example 'mobile' entity not maintaining the ManyToOne relation it always inserts NULL in foreign key column

Comment: You need to show in the question the entities and how you are saving the entity `mobile` in the db. Are you updating the association in both entities? `mobile.user = user` and `user.mobiles.add(mobile)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068742/jpa-updating-bidirectional-association

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a bidirectional association you need to update the association on both sides:

```
Mobile mobile = ...
User user = ...
user.mobiles.add(mobile);
mobile.user = user;

save(user);
```