# HashMap always returning null?

Tags: java, null, hashmap

For some odd reason my hashmap is always returning a null value even if it shouldn't be null. The row isn't null in the mysql database. I'm getting no error I did a debug test to see what it's printing out and it's returing null.

**auth.java**

```
private String uuid;
private String name;
private int bits;
private String gang;
private String rank;



public auth(String uuid, String name, int bits, String gang, String rank)
{
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.name = name;
    this.bits = bits;
    this.gang = gang;
    this.rank = rank;
}
```

**authmanager.java**

```
public HashMap<String, auth> auth = new HashMap<>();



public void saveUser(String uuid, String name, int bits, String gang, String rank)
{

    this.auth.put(uuid, new auth(uuid, name, bits, gang, rank));

}
```

**establishconnection.java**

```
public void establishProfile(Player p){

    String UUID = p.getUniqueId().toString();
    String NAME = p.getName();

    try
    {


        ResultSet query = sql.querySQL("SELECT * FROM `profiles` WHERE `UUID`= '" + UUID + "';");

        PreparedStatement CREATE = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `profiles` (`UUID`,`Name`, `Bits`, `Bans`, `Gang`, `Rank`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
        PreparedStatement LOAD = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `profiles` WHERE `UUID`= ?");

        if ( query.next() )
        {
            LOAD.setString(1, UUID);
            plugin.authmanager.saveUser(query.getString("UUID"), query.getString("Name"), query.getInt("Bits"), query.getString("Gang"), query.getString("Rank"));
            LOAD.close();
            query.close();
            p.sendMessage(tables.PROFILE_LOADED);
            Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[SQL]" +
                    " has loaded profile for " + NAME + "(" + UUID + ")"  );


        } else

        {
            CREATE.setString(1, UUID);
            CREATE.setString(2, NAME);
            CREATE.setInt(3, 0);
            CREATE.setInt(4, 0);
            CREATE.setString(5, null);
            CREATE.setString(6, "Default");

            CREATE.executeUpdate();
            CREATE.close();
            p.sendMessage(tables.PROFILE_CREATED);
            Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "[SQL]" +
                    " executed a new query for " + NAME + "(" + UUID + "}" +  plugin.authmanager.auth.get(0) );

        }


    }   catch (Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();

            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Someone's profile has failed to load!\n ERROR: " + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: where you are getting the error?is it in "this.auth.put(uuid, new auth(uuid, name, bits, gang, rank));"??

Comment: @2Hash Hi, how did you create the `UUID` in the `Player` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sticking `auth` objects into a `HashMap`, then you need to [properly override `equals` and `hashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/2646526) in your `auth` class.

Also, you should name your class `Auth` instead of `auth` to follow [standard Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html).  So rename `auth.java` to `Auth.java`, and define it as follows (requires Java 7 or higher):

**Auth.java**

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Auth {
    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private int bits;
    private String gang;
    private String rank;

    public Auth() {
    }

    public Auth(String uuid, String name, int bits, String gang, String rank) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
        this.bits = bits;
        this.gang = gang;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Auth)) {
            return false;
        }
        Auth auth = (Auth) o;
        return Objects.equals(uuid, auth.uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Auth{" +
            "uuid='" + uuid + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", bits=" + bits +
            ", gang='" + gang + '\'' +
            ", rank='" + rank + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

I only included `uuid` and not the other fields in `equals` and `hashCode` which means that if two `Auth`s have the same `uuid` they will be treated as being equal.  Including other fields will trip you up if you modify fields after the object has been `put` into a `HashMap`.  I thought that would be the easiest approach for you, but know that what exactly to include in `equals` and `hashCode` for persistent objects has been a [subject of debate for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma).

Comment: @2Hash I added an example `Auth` implementation.  Also, if you find my answer sufficient, please accept it.  Thanks!  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139/302176

Comment: how would I get a specific value from the hashmap back? How would I be able to just return the "rank" instead of the whole thing?

Comment: @2Hash Do `plugin.authmanager.auth.get(p.getUniqueId().toString())` where `p` is a `Player`.

Comment: You must of answered my old question but I deleted it, but how would I be able to return just "rank" instead of all the values?

Comment: I just added a `getRank()` method to `Auth`.  `plugin.authmanager.auth.get(p.getUniqueId().toString()).getRank()` will get just the rank.  If you need other values, you should add the appropriate get methods for them as well.

Comment: One more thing how would I give "gang" a certain value? Like for instance if someone makes a gang named "dog" the value in the hashmap where gang is would become "dog" for that user.