# How to update entity using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dao

I have entity user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_user")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "user_id"))
public class User extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Login, unique
     */
    private String email;

    private String username;

    /**
     * Secret for signing-in
     */
    private String password;

    /**
     * Type of user
     */
    private UserType userType;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "view_user_to_requestSet", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "requestSet_id")})
    private Set<RequestSet> setOfRequesSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "view_user_to_requestSetCreator", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "requestSet_id")})
    private Set<RequestSet> setOfRequesSetCreator = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "view_user_to_userTask", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "userTask_id")})
    private Set<UserTask> setOfUserTask = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    .
    .
..... GET AND SET
```

Base object is:
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseObject {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "entity_id")
private Long id;

/**
 *
 * @return true if the entity hasn't been persisted yet
 */
@Transient
public boolean isNew() {
    return id == null;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

The proble is, when I try to UPDATE object, I am getting errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_5fa729oayn43ynq4v2y4d9qcn]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '5' for key 'UK_5fa729oayn43ynq4v2y4d9qcn'
```

For update entity I am using:

```
@Transactional
public void save(User value){
   em.merge(value);
}
```

I am dont know why I am getting this error, how can I update my object? Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
I update:

```
User u = em.find(persistedType, id); //get user by ID
u.getSetOfRequesSet().add(requestSet); //add one otem to set
userDap.merge(u); //save
```

Comment: That doesn't define HOW you attempt to update an object. Where do you get the object from? em.find() ? query? then is it detached? then you update some field(s) whilst detached?

Comment: Is there a transaction including both loading and updating of the user? If not I believe the entity gets detached so that Hibernate maybe does not know any more that it is the same as the one in database. Does it work with such a transaction or if you load the entity before merging in "save"?

Comment: Are there multiple RequestSets with same ID?

Comment: Yes. I want save `requestSet` with id `1` for more `users`.

Comment: If you just do a find then do an update you have no need to do a "merge", since the objects will be "managed" ... assuming all of that is in a single transaction. What is "requestSet" ? Is it already persistent, or a new object?

Comment: just use repository, it will do the work for you, no need to explicitly call entity manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your update duplicates entries in the set (em.merge).
To prevent the duplication you should merge set explicitly. Do as following.

1. Add method merge to User:

   ```
   protected User merge(User other) {
       // Just assign all data members(2 examples here)
       setEmail(other.getEmail());
       ....
       setSetOfRequesSet(other.getSetOfRequesSet());
       ...            
   }
   ```
2. Prepare an updated object instance:

   ```
   User updated = em.find(persistedType, id); //get user by ID
   updated.getSetOfRequesSet().add(requestSet); //add one item to set
   ```
3. Update the existing db entity:

   ```
   User existing = em.find(persistedType, id);
   existing.merge(updated);
   ```

Not necessary to cal to em.merge after the update, since save will be just done at the end of a transaction.

You can find the explanation [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/08/update-hibernate-jpa-entity-collection.html).