# Why is Hibernate querying twice?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

While testing implementation of JPA into Spring I found out that my query is querying twice instead of once.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "superfan_star")
public class Star implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String nickname;
    private String description;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String backgroundImage;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "starId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<Media> medias;
}
```

This is model class.

```
@Service
public class SuperfanStarService
{
    @Autowired
    private StarRepository starRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<Star> getStars()
    {
        QStar qStar = QStar.star;
        QMedia qMedia = QMedia.media;

        List<Star> stars =
                new JPAQuery(em)
                .from(qStar)
                .where(qStar.id.eq(19))
                .list(qStar);

        return stars;
    }
}
```

This is my service class.

> 20160915 20:52:59.119 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG j.sqlonly -  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
>       9. select star0_.id as id1_2_, star0_.background_image as backgrou2_2_, star0_.created as created3_2_, star0_.description as
>   descript4_2_, star0_.name as name5_2_, star0_.nickname as
>   nickname6_2_, star0_.thumbnail as thumbnai7_2_, star0_.updated as
>   updated8_2_ from superfan_star star0_ inner join superfan_media
>   medias1_ on star0_.id=medias1_.star_id where star0_.id=19
>
> 20160915 20:52:59.173 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG j.sqlonly -  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
>       9. select medias0_.star_id as star_id11_2_0_, medias0_.id as id1_1_0_, medias0_.id as id1_1_1_, medias0_.created as created2_1_1_,
>   medias0_.description as descript3_1_1_, medias0_.end_time as
>   end_time4_1_1_, medias0_.is_approve as is_appro5_1_1_,
>   medias0_.is_approved_final as is_appro6_1_1_, medias0_.is_pushed as
>   is_pushe7_1_1_, medias0_.is_represent as is_repre8_1_1_,
>   medias0_.length as length9_1_1_, medias0_.released as release10_1_1_,
>   medias0_.star_id as star_id11_1_1_, medias0_.teleport_media_id as
>   telepor12_1_1_, medias0_.thumbnail as thumbna13_1_1_, medias0_.title
>   as title14_1_1_, medias0_.work_end as work_en15_1_1_,
>   medias0_.work_start as work_st16_1_1_, medias0_.youtube_id as
>   youtube17_1_1_, medias0_.youtube_title as youtube18_1_1_ from
>   superfan_media medias0_ where medias0_.star_id=19

As you can see, it's querying twice instead of once, probably because of inverse update? Is there any way to make my JPA model query only once?

Comment: While there is an accepted answer I suspect there maybe something else at play here. I note you have a Lombok @Data which I believe overrides equals and hashcode based on all fields which is dangerous in a JPA entity as it can trigger lots of additional data being loaded when associated items are added to hash based collections.

What happens if you remove this?

Comment: @AlanHay Yeah I found out that Lombok is causing problems for lists as it's querying medias for each Star. I'm trying to see if there's a way to use Lombok without querying everything but there doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected. The first query gets the `Star` entity with id = 19 from the database, and the second query gets the linked `Media` entities for that `Star` entity from the database. (Carefully look at the log of the SQL statements to understand what is being queried).

Note that you specified `FetchType.EAGER` on the `medias` field in class `Star`:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "starId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Set<Media> medias;
```

Eager fetching means that when you do a query for one or more `Star` objects, Hibernate immediately gets the linked `Media` objects - as opposed to lazy fetching, which means that the second query will not be done immediately, but only when necessary (when you access the `medias` member variable).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought first query's inner join is all that's needed to get the object, and didn't realize that second query is needed to link Media entity.

Answer (score 1):

While there is an accepted answer I suspect there maybe something else at play here. I note you have a Lombok `@Data` which I believe overrides `equals()` and `hashcode()` based on all fields which is dangerous in a JPA entity as it can trigger lots of additional data being loaded when associated items are added to hash based collections.

*Yeah I found out that Lombok is causing problems for lists as it's querying medias for each Star. I'm trying to see if there's a way to use Lombok without querying everything but there doesn't seem to be a way.*

Firstly, I would suggest not implementing `equals()` and `hashcode()` based on all fields of your entity: that is the root cause of your problem and makes no sense anyway - base them on a unique business key if you have one available. Essentially two entities are equal if they have the same id but see here  however:

[The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma).

Additionally, hashcode() should be based on immutable fields - see here:

http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2012/03/hashset-java-puzzler/.

Lombok's `@Data` just aggregates other individual annotations. So you can remove it, use the individual `@Getter` `@Setter` and `@ToString` Lombok annotations and write your own sensible implementations of equals() and hashcode() when required:

https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html