# Can a Kotlin data class equals() method be used without further modification in conjunction with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) has a Data class that comes with `toString(), equals(), hashCode(), and copy()`.

Can `equals() and hashCode()` be used "Straight out of the box" without further tuning for JPA classes?  We usually have to spend a lot of time reading up on "Natural Keys", the persistence context lifecycle, etc. in articles linked below before feeling confident that we are doing the right thing:

- [Equals and Hashcode](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode?_sscc=t)
- [the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma)

Can we simply rely on Kotlin's `equals() and hashcode()` implementations now?

Comment: No. The data class equals method uses all the fields, including the autogenerated ID, to compare entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, data classes in Kotlin should not be used unless you really understand what you are doing.

Overriding `equals`/`hashCode` on mutable data can cause a problem.
Consider you have added instance of a mutable class to `HashSet`, then changed some if properties of that instance.
This affects value returned by `hashCode`.

In turn, this makes it impossible for `HashSet` to find the instance, since it will look for it in completely different hashtable entry.
You won't be able to remove this instance from `HashSet`!

Good examples of candidates to be data classes in kotlin are: complex numbers, constant-sized vectors.
Bad examples are: JPA entities, DTOs.

As for JPA, these articles are opinionated.
There's another opinion: you should not override `equals` and `hashCode` for JPA entities at all.

Rationale: JPA providers (Hibernate, EclipseLink) *must* guarantee that `a === b` iff a and b have the same primary key in table, and both a and b are in persistent state.
This contract may be broken for detached entities.
But, in my opinion working with detached entities is a bad practice that one should avoid.
This only thing that may have sence is to store detached entities to merge them in another JPA transaction.

Answer (score 1):

JPA entities should depend on object identity, not on primary keys being equal - that's roughly 90% of what object-relational mapping is all about. Having a JPA implementation jump through all sorts of loops to create, maintain and propagate the [Identity Map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) and then ignoring it might be a sign that you don't need JPA at all, and will cause problems. Especially if you are not 100% aware of what you are doing.

That said, probably you can use Kotlin data classes in many cases, provided that:

- you don't store persistent objects in maps and sets
- you keep the default constructor and don't try to touch object initialization in any way (providing default values etc)