# Extending the Kotlin Data Class for use with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, dsl

Kotlin has a `Data` class that automatically implements `equals` and `hashcode`, but these are still [not automatically usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822804/can-a-kotlin-data-class-equals-method-be-used-without-further-modification-in) in a JPA context.

In order to remedy this I was wondering what it would take to extend the `Data` type in order to either assign a "Business Key" or an `id` property that is `final` and `non updatable` and is initialized with a `UUID` that serves as the [business key](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/), and have `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods use that property for their implementation.

I was thinking roughly something like this:

```
jpa class User(id: JpaId, val name: String, val age: Int)

jpa class User(bid: JpaBid, val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Instead of using a `Data` class like this:

```
data class User(bid: long, val name: String, val age: Int)
```

We are using a new type of class `jpa`.  We also have two new types, `JpaId` and `JpaBid` that are used to determine whether the id property should be a `UUID` or a business key, like an ISBN number, sku, etc.

If a `JpaId` type is used then the key is automatically generated.  If a `JpaBid` is used then the key should be supplied in the constructor.  This would ensure that as soon as a JPA entity is constructed, it can be uniquely identified.  Thoughts?  Is this something that is very straight forward to do in Kotlin, or do we need to get up in the JVM grill (Brand new to Kotlin)?

Comment: This would be a feature proposal for Kotlin, not something you could easily do yourself.

Comment: It's too bad Kotlin Github issues are disabled.  I would put a feature request in.

Comment: have a look at the Kotlin Evolution and Enhancement Process repository, that's where all these things are discussed and you can put in new proposals via pull request: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP

Comment: Super - Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/93