# Are there any drawbacks to marking a @id JPA annotated property as final?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

A lot of JPA entity demo classes have the following snippets:

```
 @Id
 private Long id;
```

Can anyone see any drawbacks to always marking the `id` property as final?

```
 @Id
 private final Long id;
```

It seems like we almost always want to do this in order to preserve the entities identity.

Comment: Because then there's no way to persist the entity?

Comment: That's a good reason :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

It makes using the JPA class impossible.

### Elaboration

`final` is a Java keyword, not a framework keyword. Java doesn't care what the contract for a JPA entity is. You cannot declare a final field that is not uninitialized, since, by contract, a final field can be written only once.

Also, it is not true that ID properties are immutable. For starters, they change when an object is serialized - a null ID is replaced by a generated ID. Less trivially, when an entity is deleted from a database, its ID is nullified.

Comment: Hmmm - Initially I was thinking that it could be initialized in the constructor (So no database assigned key) - but IIUC JPA requires an empty constructor so the field cannot be initialized during onstruction right?

Comment: Yes, and also that is generally not how you persist objects using JPA. You first fill in the entity and then persist it (thus giving it a database ID). A JPA entity can live perfectly well in an unpersisted state, as a POJO.

Comment: True - Trying to figure out the fastest simplest way to implement equals and hashcode - and if we can assign the primary key upfront and never change it - then we can base equals and hashcode on it - Asked about it for Kotlin earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838256/extending-the-kotlin-data-class-for-use-with-jpa  - Lombok has annotations in this space as well.

Comment: So basically the drawback is that it makes using the JPA class impossible :) ?

Comment: In a nutshell, yes :>

Comment: That settles that :)