# How to test Hibernate object equality in test code?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got a Hibernate class that I do not implement an equals method on.

My service layer has many methods which return this class.

For example, one of my service layer methods is:

```
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
}
```

where `User` is simply

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
}
```

In my test code, I would like to assert equality between the objects the service methods return and the objects I expect them to return.

However, it makes no sense to implement an equals method on the Hibernate class which checks that all fields are equal (as discussed in [The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma)).

At the moment to solve this I'm converting my Hibernate class into a class which does have an equals method which checks each field is equal. It works, but it's not too elegant.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any business key in your entity classes?

Comment: Yeh but I want to assert that all fields are equal, not just that the business keys are equal. I'll post up my class so the question is more clear.

Comment: Which assertion library? Usually, assertion libraries provide means to compare objects field by field, or using a custom comparator. In AssertJ, you would use `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively()`, for instance

Comment: Ah interesting, using junit5 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Off the suggestion in the comments, this does pretty much what I'm looking for - https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `assertj`, you can use the built-in recursive comparison method to do a field-by-field comparison instead of using the `equals` method comparison. For example:

```
assertThat(result).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expected);
```