# Spring boot - many to many association not removing join table data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have an issue with a many-to-many relation in Spring Boot. Code is as follows:

```
public class Task {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE}, fetch = EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "task_tag",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
  )
  @Builder.Default
  private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

  public void addTags(Collection<Tag> tags) {
    tags.forEach(this::addTag);
  }

  public void addTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tags.add(tag);
    tag.getTasks().add(this);
  }

  public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
    tags.remove(tag);
    tag.getTasks().remove(this);
  }

  public void removeTags() {
    for (Iterator<Tag> iterator = this.tags.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Tag tag = iterator.next();
      tag.getTasks().remove(this);
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Task)) return false;
    return id != null && id.equals(((Task) o).getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return id.intVal();
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Tag {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE}, mappedBy = "tags", fetch = EAGER)
  @Builder.Default
  private final Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Tag tag = (Tag) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, tag.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return id.intVal();
  }

}
```

Of course, I have the `task_tag` table where, after inserting a tag in a task and saving that task, an entry appears. However, when I delete a tag (or clear them), the entries do not get deleted from the join table. This is the test:

```
@Test
  void entityIntegration() {
    Task task = taskRepo.save(...);

    Tag tag1 = Tag.builder().name(randomString()).build();
    Tag tag2 = Tag.builder().name(randomString()).build();
    Tag tag3 = Tag.builder().name(randomString()).build();
    Tag tag4 = Tag.builder().name(randomString()).build();
    final List<Tag> allTags = Arrays.asList(tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4);
    tagRepo.saveAll(allTags);

    task.addTag(tag1);
    taskRepo.save(task);
    final Long task1Id = task.getId();
    assertTrue(tag1.getTasks().stream().map(Task::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(task1Id));

    task.clearTags();
    task = taskRepo.save(task);
    tag1 = tagRepo.save(tag1);
    assertTrue(task.getTags().isEmpty());
    assertTrue(tag1.getTasks().isEmpty());

    task.addTags(allTags);
    task = taskRepo.save(task); // FAILS, duplicate key ...

  }
```

I delete tag1 but when I try to add it back to the task, I get
[image]

The task_tag table does have a composite index formed on those two (and only) columns.

What am I doing wrong? I followed each and every suggestion and advice - using set instead of lists, having helper methods, cleaning up etc...
I can't find the bug.

Thank you!

Comment: `getClass().hashCode()` (i.e. a constant) is the worst you could possibly return from an object's `hashCode` implementation

Comment: Irrelevant, but I changed it.

Comment: After the `task.addTags(allTags)` line, if you print `task.getTags()` in a foreach loop, how many are there? Did you get the exact same problem when using `List`s? Also, I'd check if it works when you remove `cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE}` from `Tag.tasks` mapping?

Comment: Why do you need the bidirectional mapping? I would suggest a tag shouldn't know about the tasks. Anyway, are you sure that your `clearTags` or `removeTags` implementation works correctly i.e. it removes the task correctly from the tasks set? Using the id in equals/hashCode can be problematic if the object is added to a hash based collection like in your case. Try reloading the data completely after persisting (i.e. after the id is generated and set)

Comment: Yeap, those helper methods do work correctly

Comment: Maybe it is transaction/session boundaries of the test itself so the changes are not synced to db, try flushing the persistence context before `task.addTags(allTags)`.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, which is the correct (latest) implementation that you're using to clear the tags.. clearTags or removeTags.. can you update above question accordingly so it's synched up?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing that sticks out to me is that your Tag's equals and hash-code aren't matched with each other.

Your "equals" drives equality based on the object's name being the same, which makes logical sense to the mantra of "A tag is a name". But the hash-code drives based on the "id" being equivalent and doesn't use the name at all.

Forgetting JPA/Hibernate for a moment, just plain old Collections themselves get very unpredictable when these two are out of synch.

You can read more about that here and specifically why a hash-code that doesn't match equality would end up hashing to the wrong bucket and resulting in confusing keeping it all straight in HashSets: [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

There are many ways to put them back in synch (using libraries like Lombok and code-generation tools in your IDE come to mind), but instead of prescribing one, I will simply point to this web-resource that, conveniently, created a Tag with the exact same concept for his example, so I suspect you can just use this exact same pattern yourself.

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Here's another helpful SO thread I found that talks about relationships and identity/equals/hashCode as it impacts JPA: [The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma)

Answer (score -2):

Kindly add DELETE keyword to the cascade property of many to many annotation . And i believe ur annotation for task property of Tag class should be changed as below .

You can give this below mapping a try

```
public class Task {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE,DELETE}, fetch = EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "task_tag",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
  )
  @Builder.Default
  private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

  public void addTags(Collection<Tag> tags) {
    tags.forEach(this::addTag);
  }

  public void addTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tags.add(tag);
    tag.getTasks().add(this);
  }

  public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
    tags.remove(tag);
    tag.getTasks().remove(this);
  }

  public void removeTags() {
    for (Iterator<Tag> iterator = this.tags.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Tag tag = iterator.next();
      tag.getTasks().remove(this);
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Task)) return false;
    return id != null && id.equals(((Task) o).getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return id.intVal();
  }
}
```

```
public class Tag {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE,DELETE}, mappedBy = "tags", fetch = EAGER)
@JoinTable(
      name = "task_tag",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
  )
  @Builder.Default
  private final Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Tag tag = (Tag) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, tag.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return id.intVal();
  }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem and definitely adding REMOVE (instead of DELETE) there is not something that I want. I don't want my projects removed when a tag associated with them is removed.